What is the propagation delay in flip flops?
Is this the amount of time it takes to change the output once input is placed inside? In flip flops, when we input something, the output remains constant for some time until it changes. Is this amount of time the propagation delay?

Using an image from the 4013 datasheet, it is shown as the time between the clock transition and the output transition.

And, according to JEDEC (for tPLH):

The time interval between the specified reference points on the input and output voltage waveforms with the specified output changing from the defined low level to the defined high level.


NOTE In IEC 748‑2, the reference points on both the input and output waveforms have the same value, which is midway between the maximum low-level input voltage (VILmax) and the minimum high-level input voltage (VIHmin).


It is the time between the clock edge and the output getting updated with the input data.

The propagation delay in a flip-flop, or any logic device for that matter, is the time between a cause signal making a specific transition, and the effect signal making a transition in response.
When we change the data on a D-type flip flop, there's no change at the outputs. It's only when the clock input makes its active transition (usually low to high, but there are a few flip flops, not many, that use the high to low transition) that the outputs are triggered to change.
There are generally different numbers for propagation delay depending on whether the data output is rising or falling, just because of the detail of the way the outputs are implemented.
The data sheet will generally give you two numbers for propagation, a typical, and a max. Only the latter is guarranteed. If you design assuming typicals, you will come to grief sooner or later.
There are usually other inputs to a flip flop, clear for instance, that will have their own propagation delay.
It may or may not be obvious that in order to use the correct data level, the data must have settled for long enough at that level before the clock makes its transition. This is the data setup time. It also has to stay valid for a hold time after the clock transition.

Is there anything in any official standard to specify that on devices with multiple flops having a non-zero hold time, the minimum propagation delay of any of them will be at least equal to the maximum hold time, or does one merely have to hope process variations within a chip won't exceed that margin?

@supercat minimum propagation delay is rarely if ever specified. Almost all devices are usable if you assume that tpropmin is positive, ie no effect before cause. Sometimes, I've needed something tighter and assumed a figure of typical/4, and not been caught out yet. I've never seen any specification for the relationship between multiple flipflops within a package, you would have to address the specs pairwise if you wanted them to operate together.

It seems to be common accepted practice to assume that when multiple flops are driven by a common clock, and the one of them feeds the input of another, the latter flop will on each clock cleanly capture the state the output had before that clock edge; I wonder why standards wouldn't be written in a manner that indicate a useful range of circumstances where this would be guaranteed to work?

@supercat common accepted practice, but wrong if applied blindly. Many flip flops specify a hold time of zero, which guarantees a shift register made from them will 'just work'. Some don't, and if you try the same lazy approach, then you can't say you haven't been warned when some start failing in the field under extreme conditions. Where you really need an ice-bag on the forehead is the timing specifications for I/O flop cells in in FPGAs, which is why we all leave it up to the PAR and timing analyser tools.

Most such chips are designed in such a way that the propagation time would, in the absence of process variations, be so much greater than the hold time, that the only way things could fail for intra-chip feedback would be if there were massive process variations within a single chip; it irks me that designers don't bother to write specs that would allow chips to be used efficiently without having to rely upon things that should be guaranteed by the chip's internal design but spec-writers didn't bother to actually state.

@supercat now I'm intrigued. Could you link to a data sheet where an attempt to use intra-chip feedback would fail worst case timing.

I don't remember any examples off hand, but on the occasions where I've seen a data sheet specify a positive hold times for a registered inputs (not terribly common, admittedly), I've found the existence of a specified hold time that would abide that constraint to be a pleasant surprise.  Actually, I often wonder if there would have been any practical difficulties, when designing specs for registered inputs, having separate clock logic thresholds for setup/hold time measurements and propagation-time measurements, such that controlling slew rate on the clock would yield guaranteed behavior.

If when using a 5-volt supply, setup hold times were measured from when the clock signal reaches 0.5 volt, hold times from when it reaches 1.5, propagation minimum from when it reaches 2.0, and propagation maximum from when it reaches 3.0, then if a device with a 50ns hold time which receives a signal would be guaranteed to have its clock input reach 1.5 volts 50ns before a device with a 0ns propagation time which sends it could have its input reach 2.0 volts, correct behavior would be guaranteed.  I wonder if engineering chips to such specs would have added any significant dififculty?
